# How to detect Default Dialer app changes?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

#### Context

I'm implementing [RCC](https://www.gsma.com/futurenetworks/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/RCC.71_v2.0.pdf) and as seen in this spec by GSMA, I need to be able to detect default dialer changes.

According to the spec section B.1.1:

> On Android™ OS version superior or equal to 7.0, (...) to be notified of Default SMS app changes and Default Dialler change, the RCS client shall listen for the broadcast of the Android™ Intents: “ACTION_DEFAULT_SMS_PACKAGE_CHANGED”. “ACTION_DEFAULT_DIALER_CHANGED”

Currently, I'm using, `TelecomManager.ACTION_DEFAULT_DIALER_CHANGED` in a sample project like this:

```xml
<receiver android:name="BroadcastTest">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.telecom.action.DEFAULT_DIALER_CHANGED"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The `BroadcastTest` class is an empty `BroadcastReceiver` that prints a log.

#### Problem

When updating the dialer app **in Settings**, no broadcast is received in the receiver. I tried playing around with the priority but no success either. I'm receiving the broadcast if the request was made by the app, however, I need to do perform some behaviour if the user changed in the settings too (or by using other app).

It seems that this broadcast is not being sent, which makes the implementation of this spec hard.

The app in question has call permissions. No broadcast is received whether the app is default dialer or not.

#### Workaround

I've came up with a workaround that involves registering a content observer to be notified of changes in the `dialer_default_application` URI (`content://settings/secure/dialer_default_application`).

However, as defined in the spec, we should be receiving this broadcast

#### Question

Am I doing something wrong when implementing this broadcast? Does anyone receive this broadcast (probably a device specific problem)? Is there any problem in using the workaround solution (`dialer_default_application` is a hidden constant in `Settings.Secure`)?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the platform source code ([TelephonyServiceImpl class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Telecomm/+/2750faaa1ec819eed9acffea7bd3daf867fda444/src/com/android/server/telecom/TelecomServiceImpl.java#882)), it looks like the behaviour you're describing is the one to expect:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_DEFAULT_DIALER_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName);
mContext.sendBroadcastAsUser(intent, new UserHandle(ActivityManager.getCurrentUser()));
```

Instead of sending a broadcast to all interested BroadcastReceivers, it calls `sendBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle user)`, which will only send it to the current user (meaning app).

I guess the documentation for [`ACTION_DEFAULT_DIALER_CHANGED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager.html#ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER) could make it clearer though.